# Hough Transform: Converted polar coordinates back to Cartesian, but still can't plot them

Tags: matlab, image-processing, hough-transform

So I have already implemented every part of a Hough Transform on my own, except for actually plotting the lines back onto the original image.

I can set up my array of data that I have like this.

```
points | theta | rho
-------|-------|----
[246,0]   -90    -246
[128,0]   -90    -128
[9,0]     -90     -9
[0,9]      0      9     
[0,128]    0     128
[0,246]    0     246
```

The points are the points that were converted **from** the peaks in Polar Coordinates. So now I need to draw all six of these lines and I have had no luck.

Edit

---

So I tried to change my code based off suggestions. This is what I came up with.

```
function help(img, outfile, peaks, rho, theta)
    imshow(img);
    x0 = 1;
    xend = size(img,2); 
    peaks_len=length(peaks);
    for i=1:peaks_len
        peak=peaks(i,:);
        r_ind=peak(1);
        t_ind=peak(2);
        r=rho(r_ind);
        th=theta(t_ind);
        %display([r,th,peak]);

        %// if a vertical line, then draw a vertical line centered at x = r
%         display([r, th]);

        if (th == 0)
            display('th=0');
            display([1, size(img,1)]);
            line([r r], [1 size(img,1)], 'Color', 'green');
        else
            %// Compute starting y coordinate
            y0 = abs((-cosd(th)/sind(th))*x0 + (r / sind(th)))+11;%-25; 

            %// Compute ending y coordinate
            yend = abs((-cosd(th)/sind(th))*xend + (r / sind(th)))+11;%-25;
            display('y');
            display([y0, yend]);
            display('x');
            display([x0 xend]);
             %// Draw the line
            line([x0 xend], [y0 yend], 'Color', 'green');
        end
    end
end
```

I had to change from `r==0` to `th==0` because `th=0` would give `NAN` errors when r was not 0.

Based off the peaks, I then used that to get the data I needed to then calculate some values... but for some reason this isn't plotting well.

If you notice the + 11 for both y values. I had to do that to get the lines to be where they need to. I have a feeling something else went wrong.

I did change it so that my Rho values are all now positive.

Comment: You are not using `abs` properly. I meant in the accumulation phase, not the drawing phase. Don't take the `abs` when drawing the lines. When you calculate `rho` during the transform stage, take the absolute value there. You seem to have misunderstood me.

Comment: I actually change my rho completely so that there are no negatives.

Comment: That's fine. Don't use `abs` when drawing the lines. They won't appear on the image because they would technically be out of bounds.

Comment: It seems that matlab here counts y values down positively. So without the abs, nothing shows.

Comment: When you show the image yes. Also, I'm assuming that's the convention you used when calculating the transform. TBH I really don't know how you did it. Either way, good luck!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you recall from the parameterization of the Hough space, the direct relation between `rho`,`theta` to `x,y` is:

```
rho = x*cos(theta) + y*sin(theta)
```

Bear in mind that `x,y` represent the **column** and **row** location respectively.  In addition, the origin is defined at the **top-left** corner of the image.  Now that you want to plot the equation of the line, you have your `rho` and `theta`.  Simply re-arrange the equation so that you can solve for an equation of the line of the form `y = mx + b`:

[image]

As such , simply loop over each `rho` and `theta` you have and draw a line that starts from the origin at `x = 0` up to the limit of your image `x = width-1`.  However, because MATLAB is 1-indexed, we need to go from `x = 1` to `x = width`.  Supposing that your `rho` and `theta` are stored in separate arrays of the same lengths and you have your edge image stored in `im`, you can do something like this:

```
imshow(im); %// Show the image
hold on; %// Hold so we can draw lines
numLines = numel(rho); %// or numel(theta);

%// These are constant and never change
x0 = 1;
xend = size(im,2); %// Get the width of the image

%// For each rho,theta pair...
for idx = 1 : numLines
    r = rho(idx); th = theta(idx); %// Get rho and theta
    %// Compute starting y coordinate
    y0 = (-cosd(th)/sind(th))*x0 + (r / sind(th)); %// Note theta in degrees to respect your convention

    %// Compute ending y coordinate
    yend = (-cosd(th)/sind(th))*xend + (r / sind(th));

    %// Draw the line
    line([x0 xend], [y0 yend], 'Color', 'blue');
end
```

The above code is pretty simple.  First, show the image using [`imshow`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imshow.html) in MATLAB.  Next, use `hold on` so we can draw our lines in the image that will go on top of the image.  Next, we calculate how many `rho,theta` pairs there are, and then we define the two `x` coordinates to be 1 and `width` as we will use these to determine where the starting and ending `y` coordinates are, given these `x` coordinates.  Next, for each `rho,theta` pair we have, determine the corresponding `y` coordinates, then use [`line`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/line.html) to draw a line from the starting and ending `(x,y)` coordinates in blue.  We repeat this until we run out of lines.

Don't be alarmed if the `y` coordinates that are produced go out of bounds in the image.  `line` will be intelligent enough to simply cap the result.

## When `theta = 0`

The above code works assuming that you have no vertical lines detected in the Hough Transform, or when `theta = 0`.  If `theta = 0` (like in your case), this means that we have a **vertical** line which would thus produce an infinite slope and our formulation of `y = mx + b` is invalid.  Should `theta = 0`, the equation of the line becomes `x = rho`.  As such, you will need an additional `if` statement inside your loop that will detect this:

```
imshow(im); %// Show the image
hold on; %// Hold so we can draw lines
numLines = numel(rho); %// or numel(theta);

%// These are constant and never change
x0 = 1;
xend = size(im,2); %// Get the width of the image

%// For each rho,theta pair...
for idx = 1 : numLines
    r = rho(idx); th = theta(idx); %// Get rho and theta

    %// if a vertical line, then draw a vertical line centered at x = r
    if (th == 0)
        line([r r], [1 size(im,1)], 'Color', 'blue');
    else
        %// Compute starting y coordinate
        y0 = (-cosd(th)/sind(th))*x0 + (r / sind(th)); %// Note theta in degrees to respect your convention

        %// Compute ending y coordinate
        yend = (-cosd(th)/sind(th))*xend + (r / sind(th));

        %// Draw the line
        line([x0 xend], [y0 yend], 'Color', 'blue');
   end
end
```

---

In order to draw the vertical line, I need to know how **high** the image is so that we can draw a vertical line from the top of the image (`y = 1`) down to the bottom of the image (`y = height`) which is anchored at `x = rho`.  As such, the above code should now properly handle any line, as well as the degenerate case when the slope is infinite.  Therefore, this second version of the code is what you're after.

---

Good luck!

Comment: So the second case should work for all lines, vertical,  horizontal, and other?

Comment: @ChrisJones - Yup!  Bear in mind that this doesn't handle negative `rho`, as I'm assuming that the origin of your Hough space is at the top left corner of the image... so you won't be able to visualize these.

Comment: As you can see though, the image has negative rhos.. I also put in some wrong angles too.. this did work for non vertical lines though.

Comment: @ChrisJones - How did you get negative `rho`? That only happens if your origin is not at the top left corner.  Negative `rho` wouldn't be possible if your origin is well defined.

Comment: @ChrisJones - Consider making the `rho` strictly positive by taking the absolute value of the `rho` when you calculate it in the accumulator space.  Check out the Wiki article for its implications: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform#Theory

Comment: So I have put it all in positive... and now it isn't even plotting the lines

Comment: I can't comment on why that is as I don't know how you wrote the algorithm for Hough

Comment: It is odd, it plotted the horizontal before.. I'll see what I can find elsewhere in the code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70352/discussion-between-chris-jones-and-rayryeng).

Comment: So... somehow... this worked.. like I went to sleep and now it works. Not sure what I changed.. but it works. Thanks!!!

Comment: Lmao wtf? No problem! Good luck!

Comment: I can't really explain..maybe it was something small I wasn't seeing last night .... although I didn't get it to work on slanted lines..but that is more due to some other issues I think. Still, this makes me feel so much better.

Comment: @ChrisJones - If the lines are slightly slanted, it may be due to numerical imprecision.  Like the slopes could be very huge and finding those particular points on the line may overflow the calculations... I can't say for sure... but I'm glad you figured it out.  Thanks for accepting my answer!